# Get dynamically created names of dynamical links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a link for a set of documents. They are created dynamically, thus the names are also different, f.ex. Test, Test2, so one.
I need to show the link like "Document TestN", where links changed according to the current document. I can now create the links by  a href="id" onklick=bla+bla+bla", but the name does not change. Instead of 'Dashboard' I need to get 'Dashboard of "ConcreteSite"', where I can get names by pageHeader:

```js
document.getElementById("pageHeading").appendChild(pageHeading);
```

```html
   
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
  var siteNameAsParam = window.location.search; 
  var scrt_var = siteNameAsParam.split("siteName=")[1];
</script>
<p>You are here: <a href="site-home-bpp" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?siteName='+scrt_var;return false;">Dashboard</a> </p>
```

Comment: Please provide code showing what your problem is and what you have tried to solve it so far.

Comment: Give us example of your work please.

Comment: changed question in more clear way

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I think this is what you're after but more detail on what you're trying to do would be great.

```
<p>You are here: <a href="site-home-bpp">Dashboard</a> </p>

<p>You are here: <a href="site-home-bpp-to">Dashboard</a> </p>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      var siteNameAsParam = window.location.search;
      var scrt_var = siteNameAsParam.split("siteName=")[1];
      links[i].href = links[i].href + '?siteName=' + scrt_var;
      links[i].innerText += ' fred';
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

This does the following:

- On page load gets all links on the page
- loops through the links and grabs the query strings from the url
- splits the query string on siteName
- sets each link url to add the query string
- updates the links text to append the query string (or undefined if it doesn't exist (see note below)

Note: your code implies you already have a query string in the url of siteName=SITENAMEHERE.  Also, depending what you're trying to achieve, there are probably much better approaches.  This I hope answers your current question but I think you should review how other achieve what you're after.

**Update:**

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xz14tz9/3/) with a different working sample of what I think you might want.  Hopefully it helps. there are comments in the fiddle. I think you want to try doing more when the link is created (set the event listener there, update the text as desired, etc.) instead of on the click event.

Comment: I try to make a path, where user was before he comes to the particular link, for example, menu>Sites>SiteName>Documentation of SiteName. I tried to retrieve urls, but it shows exactly name of page: site-name-page, but not title - Site Name. That is why decided to do it that way. Provided code works, but, unfortunately it does not retrieve names of each dynamically created link

Comment: The code sample i provided was intended to replace what you have in your question. Instead of adding the href on click do it after the page loads.   If you mean you are creating links after the page loads (i.e. the user clicks a button to load a document and links are created) you could set the href at that time in that eventListener.  Or you could use jquery and use the .on() method to add event listeners to dynamically created elements.

Comment: I've added jsfiddle that might help. Your question needs more examples of what you're trying to do for me to help more than this.  Good luck.